# What is the point of finding the standard form of a quadratic form?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

In a problem sheet for my linear algebra course I was asked to find the standard form of the quadratic form $Q=8x_1^2 + 2x_2^2 +3x_3^2 +8x_2x_3$.

Following the steps in the lecture notes I arrived at the expression $Q=8y_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}((\sqrt{65}+5)y_2^2 + (5-\sqrt{65})y_3^2)$.

I am not sure whether the co-efficients are correct as the solution has not been given yet but my question is what benefit does re writing Q in this form give, and how does it link with the rest of linear algebra?

Edit:

let $X= \begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}$,

$Q=X^T M X$,

Where $M$ is  the matrix of coefficients,$ \begin{pmatrix} 8&0&0\\0&2&4\\0&4&3\end{pmatrix}$.

$X$ and $Y$ are related by $X=PY$.
Where $P$ is the eigen vector matrix of M.

Comment: One thing the standard form tells you immediately is whether your form is positive definite (or semidefinite). It also lets you solve its preimage problem (i.e., find vectors $v$ such that $Q\left(v\right) = b$ for a fixed scalar $b$).

Comment: Canonical (or standard) forms have many advantages. This is like asking why "Jordan canonical form" is anything good "in the rest of linear algebra". Well....

Comment: @Vizag Sorry I forgot to relate x and y

Comment: @amd  I have made an edit, is the second form still wrong? In my lecture notes a similar quadratic form was given in x and reduced to just the square of y terms, where x and y are related as described above.

Comment: In fact we can make a linear change of coordinates $(x_i) \to (z_i)$ so that $Q = z_1^2 + z_2^2 - z_3^2$, and I would call *this* expression a standard form.

Comment: I am getting the feeling that making a new variable and relating it in such a way isnt often done, ill ask my professor when i see him next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drop any requirement about orthogonality, you can solve $Q^T D Q = H$ with all rational numbers, $D$ diagonal, and $\det Q = 1.$ The equivalence relation is called **congruence**, so some books call this process congruence diagonalization. It is simply repeated "completing the square" done in reverse order.

In turn this shows what you get with Sylvester Inertia.

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 4 \\ 
0 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 4 \\ 
0 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 4 \\ 
0 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 4 \\ 
0 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 5 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
8 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 4 \\ 
0 & 4 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$